# How do you handle patch versions with puppet?

Tags: vagrant, version, puppet

We use vagrant with puppet. Now there is a question about setting the version of different applications.

How specific do you ensure versions with puppet? For example mysql: Do you ensure to have version 5.5 or even more specific like 5.5.35? What is the best approach? Whats your experience?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you manage your software.

The most suitable way is using packages in your OS's favourite format, e.g. `rpm` or `deb`.

On Debian, this would be a way to make Puppet install a specific version:

```
package {
  "mysql-server-5.5":
    ensure => "5.5.35";
}
```

In Puppet up to and including `3.x`, the desired version is used as a value for the `ensure` property. In the future, there will likely be a `version` property instead.